# C++: Deleting a node in the middle of a singly linked list?

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list, nodes

Here is my code:

```
template<class L>
Node<L>* LinkedList<L>::DeleteNode(L toDelete)
{
        Node<L>* current;
        Node<L>* trail;

        if(head == NULL)
        {
                cout << "\n\nCannot delete from an empty list.\n\n";
        }
        else
        {
            if(head->next == NULL)
            {
                if(head->data == toDelete)
                {
                    current = head;
                    delete current;
                    head = current;
                    tail = current;
                    cout << "\nObject found. The list is now empty.\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "\nObject not found.\n";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                current = head;

                while(current->data != toDelete && current->next != NULL)
                {
                        trail = current;
                        current = current->next;
                }

                if(current->data == toDelete)
                {
                    if(current->next == NULL)
                    {
                        trail->next = NULL;
                        current = trail;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // having error here
                        trail->next = current->next;
                        current = trail;
                        delete trail;

                    }

                    cout << "\nNode found and deleted.\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "\nObject not found.\n";
                }
            }
        }

        return head;
}
```

I marked the specific line at which I am having trouble (when trying to remove a node from the middle (when next is not null)). I have tried multiple variations of that block and still nothing.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to initial `trail` to `NULL` and handle the case where the head is being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply deliting the wrong Node, at this stage:
trail is holding the last Node befor the Node that should be deleted.
Try this instead:

```
{
trail->next = current->next;
delete current;
//you may want to add: current=trail->next; if you are planing to keep working with 
// the rest of the list
}
```

You should also review your code block preior to this:

```
if(current->next == NULL)
            {
                trail->next = NULL;
                current = trail;
            }
```

you are actualy not delting enything here, it really should be:

```
if((current->next == NULL)
{
    trail->next = NULL;
    delete current;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are assigning the address current points to, to be the same as trail points to, and then freeing that resource, which I don't think was the intent.

Right now you are actually splitting your list as you are re-assign current to point to trail right before deleting trail (when you wanted to free current, which based on your while loop points to what you want to delete)

It makes more sense to:

`trail->next = current->next;
delete current;`

I'm not sure how your other cases are working as expected... the code looks funny to me.  For example, in your case of it being the end of the list you're not freeing any resource (but you just deleted something, why is no resource getting freed?)  In the case of deleting the head, you've lost your list and created a memory leak with your current implementation.

All that said - it's a good start, but I'd take a step back and prototype the interfaces your linked-list should provide to be effective as well as list out the possible edge cases (such as deleting the head).